# How do i sort a cart by size in magento

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

i have the following code in my cart

```
$cartitems = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
    ->setQuote($quote)
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addOrder('name', 'asc');
```

it sorts the items but only by half, all the products in the catalog are configureable products using a size attribute, so while the products are being sorted, their sizes are not, i want to sort by name then size (with size, preferable by their position)

i've tried adding `addOrder('size', 'asc')` but it doesn't work saying it can't find a field by that name (i know the attribute_code is correct)

Comment: It gives following error in Magento 1.7.0.2

`Fatal error: Call to a member function setFinalPrice() on a non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Item\Abstract.php on line 73`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've been able to make a compromise in my code, while i still don't know how to sort the cart by my size attribute i was able to do the secondary sort by sku as the pairs of configurable and simple products in sales_flat_order has the same sku which belonged to the simple products (while the name came from the configurable)

naturally, this will break if i create a smaller size but the sku is greater than even the largest size (my skus are all numbers) however it's the best i can do

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to **attribute** management, choose your **size** attribute. And set "Used for sorting in product listing" to **Yes**

After that, the new attribute should appear in 'system configuration -> catalog -> frontend -> Product Listing Sort by'

Comment: i'm asking about the **cart**, the setting there was already set to Name but the products in the cart was never sorted by name but by their item_id in sales_flat_quote_item, plus even if the option you mentioned did apply to the cart (which i doubt it does) and there was an error in the template that stopped it working it doesn't allow sorting by both **Name** and **ATTRIBUTE** it only allows sorting by one option so my problem isn't solved